# What's the difference between Const and Constant?

Tags: haskell

There seems to be two implementations of the constant functor:

- [`Const`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Const) in `Control.Applicative`
- [`Constant`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Data-Functor-Constant.html) in `Data.Functor.Constant`

Why do both of them exist, and which one should I use?

Comment: well the first one seems to have more "batteries-included" ;)

Comment: This is strange. `Data.Functor.Constant` seems to be released in 2010, long after `Control.Applicative`. And it provides something that is less useful than what there was already available. So it really looks like `Constant a b` is pretty much useless...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They do the same thing indeed. As far as I'm aware of, most people use `Const` because it is older (as Bakuriu pointed out), is in `base` and has a shorter name. Case in point: `lens` uses `Const`. There was at least one [discussion about unifying them](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/17189) in the libraries mailing list back in 2012, but it didn't went through, seemingly because of differences of opinion about the name and the most appropriate module for it.

Comment: There's a [more recent proposal](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2015-July/026014.html) by Kmett to move some types from `transformers` to `base`, in which he deliberately ignores `Constant` (I get a certain "Die already!" vibe from that discussion.) (To be fair, `lens` actually provides some support for it.)